# How can I remove comments in a HTML with sed?

Tags: html, bash, sed, comments

for example I have this html code

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<!--comment-->
<!-- comment -->
<!--
comment
-->
<h2>Title2</h2>
```

and with the sed I have to get this

```
<h3>Title</h3>
<h2>Title</h2>
```

I found some command here, but they aren't work for me

```
sed '/<!--.*-->/d'
```

does not remove this

```
<!--
comment
-->
```

Comment: [You can't parse \[X\]HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, e.g.).

Comment: If you just want to output the parts where Title is, you can use grep.  `grep Title foo.html`, but I'm guessing there is more than just grepping for Tittle is involve.

Comment: When you must use `sed` (school), add this to the question (not only to the subject). Does `sed -z 's#<!--.*-->##'` work for your example? If so, you have a new `sed` version and we can look for a better command. This `sed` will delete the `<h2>` line when a comment occurs after `<h2>`.

Comment: If only `sed` is available to you and only exactly for your example: `sed '/<!--/,/-->/d' file`

Answer (score 2):

With valid HTML/XML:

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()' file.html
```

If you want to edit file inplace, add option `-L`.

If your HTML is not valid try this:

```
xmlstarlet format --recover --html file.html | xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()'
```

With xml:

```
xmlstarlet format --recover file.xml | xmlstarlet ed -d '//comment()'
```

---

To omit xml declaration in output add `--omit-decl`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use only sed (for school)